# Why the_posts_pagination function not working?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

`the_posts_pagination` function is not working: http://pastie.org/pastes/10166362/text

Here is the full code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <?php
        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'mid_size' => 2,
            'prev_text' => __( 'Newer', 'textdomain' ),
            'next_text' => __( 'Older', 'textdomain' ),
        ));
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the _relevant_ part of your code in your question instead of linking to a third-party site. Also, please specify _what_ exactly isn't working.

Comment: this might help you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174907/how-to-use-the-posts-navigation-for-wp-query-and-get-posts

Answer (score 2):

the_posts_pagination only works in post listings pages like index.php or archive.php. It will not work in a custom template, for example.

See here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination